# Stack smashing detected glGetTexImage

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is the code that causes stack smashing when run:

```
GLubyte pixels[SCREEN_WIDTH*SCREEN_HEIGHT*3];


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,fbo->renderedTexture);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixels);
```

I have made sure that the function itself is not the problem, as it works with an sdl surface.

Comment: What is `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` set to?

Comment: We do not have enough information to deduce the problem for you. Please post a minimal working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible causes:

The size of `pixels` exceeds the amount of stack left (there's only a limited amount of stack available) and that's what smashing your stack. Don't use the stack for large stuff.

Another possible cause is, that the size of `pixels` is to small for the data of the texture to fit into it with all packing parameters (alignment, row stride) applied.